# Confusing preposition

Tags: prepositions

I have heard about the following sentence:
   He is concerned ___ the plot.

What will be the suitable preposition in the blank?

My assumption:   in.

Answer (score 1):

There are two suitable prepositions, **about** and **with**. Unfortunately, **in** would not be appropriate.

From the Oxford Dictionary:

> **about** (preposition): 1. On the subject of; concerning.
>
> *I was thinking about you.*

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/about

> **with** (preposition): 7. In relation to.
>
> *My father will be angry with me.*

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/with

Comment: In one of its usages, *concern* is a synyonym for *involve*, and in that case it wouldn't be incorrect to use *in*. If I heard "He was concerned in the plot," I would take it to mean that there was some part of the plot that involved him or was about him.

Comment: @joiedevivre I think you could say ***concerned for***, but I've never heard anyone say ***concerned in***, at least here in California.

Comment: *concerned for* wouldn't mean the same thing at all. *The plot concerned a tree-like being named Groot,* can only be rendered in passive voice with the same meaning using the preposition *in.* *Groot was concerned in the plot.* All other prepositions you've proposed would make it sound like Groot was worried about the plot, not involved in it. This usage is more common in participle phrases, though: *the characters concerned in the plot*, *the parties concerned in the case of Smith v. Jones*, *the contractors concerned in the construction project.*

Comment: I wasn't suggesting ***concerned for*** would mean the same -- only that it fit OK into the sentence the OP posted. And now that you mention "in" in those examples, I see that now, yes.

Comment: @joiedevivre Your example sentences are somewhat different than what the OP posted. I'm still having trouble seeing how ***in*** would fit OK in the OP's sentence.

Comment: It's likely that the OP was using "concern" in a sense that would go best with the prepositions you proposed, but if the meaning of the sentence happened to be that *he* was a character in the plot, then it's the same as the *Groot was concerned in the plot* example. Without more context, it's impossible to tell which meaning of *concern* was intended. If he was a screenwriter, *concerned with* is best. If he was a producer who thought the plot had problems, then *concerned about* is the best fit. Does that make sense?

Comment: Another possible context: *He is concerned in the plot (to assassinate the president).*

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. I've always kind of used with and about synonymously, but I realize they're slightly different in the way you describe.  I'll agree that *in* CAN fit, but it's an unusual context.

Comment: I think it seems unusual because the sentence is hanging here with no context, at all, so it makes us want to interpret "concern" in its most common sense. With enough surrounding context, it might feel like a natural fit. "Huckleberry Finn is a fictitious character. He is concerned in the plot of *Tom Sawyer* and is the main character in *Huckleberry Finn.*"

Comment: That is absolutely true. Just practically speaking, I think the OP is posting a quiz question, and likely there is no context beyond the sentence we have.

Comment: You could be right. Bad quiz question, though, with so many potential right answers. :)